# setImage:forState does not work for subclass of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I create a class RadioButton that inherited from UIButton ,and rewrite the method layoutSubViews where reset the frame of self.imageView and self.titleLabel ,when I call the method setImage:forState: of RadioButton instance,it does not work, but the method radioButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""] work. It is an interesting problem ,I appreciate so much if anyone know why and share the reason .

Comment: Can you show code

Comment: You have to show your some code. I think...

Answer (score 0):

When we set title,image for button we need to use below code

**For Button**

```
[button setTitle:@"Your Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**For Image**

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[why should not we use titleLabel](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel?language=objc)

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and
>   setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those
>   changes.
>
> **The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not**
>   **been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system
>   buttons.**

[why should we use setTitle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle?language=objc)

> Use this method to set the title for the button. The title you
>   specify derives its formatting from the button’s associated label
>   object. If you set both a title and an attributed title for the
>   button, the button prefers the use of the attributed title over this
>   one.
>
> At a minimum, you should set the value for the normal state. If a
>   title is not specified for a state, the default behavior is to use the
>   title associated with the UIControlStateNormal state. If the value for
>   UIControlStateNormal is not set, then the property defaults to a
>   system value.

[For Image](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage?language=objc)

Comment: thanks for you awser.  actrully I  used method setImage:forState  to set image for object which is subclass of UIButton ,but it has no effect.